# How to open pdf in adobe from Electron + angular

Tags: angular, electron

We have an desktop app built with angular & electron. In one scenario the response is pdf and i wanted to open the response in adobe or system default viewer for pdf. Anyone faced this scenario before, if so please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First, save that response into a local file. Then, use `shell.openItem` as:

```
const electron = require('electron').shell;
const shell = electron.shell
const path = require('path');

shell.openItem(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/pdf_file.pdf'));
```

Comment: It worked thanks.. one more question how do i save a byte array to a pdf.. should i use something like fs? i am new to angular.. that's why my questions are basic..thanks in advance

Comment: You should use 'fs' to save the data. If you want complete control over the filepath, and don't want the user to have 'Download File/Save File: Dialog' experience, the best you can do is pass the bytes to main process via 'ipc', and then use 'fs' to manage reading/writting the file.
Note: If the file size is too large, it could block the main thread. If the file size is huge, use write async methods, and transfer the data in buffer, and not all at once.

Comment: If it was helpful, please be generous to rate the comment. :)

Comment: i did rate/vote the comment the day you responded to me. but since i am a newbie it seems to be not considered. Thanks man, you reply was so helpful to me.keep going.